# $R$-module homomorphism $f$ is injective iff $f$ is a monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

**Attempt**

$(\implies)$ Assume $f: M \rightarrow N$ is injective. Let
$ \begin{cases}
g: L \rightarrow M \\
h: L \rightarrow M
\end{cases}$
be $R$-module homomorphisms, and assume that $f \circ g = f \circ h$. If $g \neq h$, then there exists $\ell \in L$ such that
$ \begin{cases}
(g(\ell)) = m_1 \\
(h(\ell)) = m_2 \end{cases}$
for distinct $m_1, m_2$ in $M$. But then
$$f(m_1) = f(g(\ell)) = f(h(\ell)) = f(m_2)$$
which violates the injectivity of $f$. Hence $g = h$ and $f$ is a monomorphism.

$(\Longleftarrow)$ Assume $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a monomorphism. Choose $L$ to be (the $R$-module) ker $(f)$, $g$ to be the inclusion ker $(f) \rightarrow M$, and $h$ to be the trivial map, i.e. $h(x) = 0$ for all $x \in L$. Now $f \circ g = f \circ h$ since they both map everything in $L$ to zero in $N$, and  since $f$ is a monomorphism this implies that $g = h$, i.e. the inclusion map $g$ is trivial, so that ker $(f)$ is trivial and $f$ is injective.

Is this kosher? The $(\Longleftarrow)$ direction feels fishy to me but I can't quite put my finger on it. It doesn't look like we are using anything particular to the category $R$-mod.